# Интерактивная круговая диаграмма

Tags: java, javafx, график, диаграммы

Не могу найти информацию о том, можно ли сделать часть круговой диаграммы (Pie Chart) JavaFX активным полем (кнопкой), чтобы нажатие на какую-нибудь из частей можно было обработать.

Comment: https://o7planning.org/ru/11105/javafx-piechart-tutorial 4-ая часть в самом низу статьи.

Comment: можно на канве нарисовать попробовать :)